# why I get this error while using templates in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to Templates and trying to get **name** and **item** but I run into weird error. I thought the problem was the **string** so I changed to **int** but it didn't work. can you help me please. Thank you!
when i delete the templates form cpp class i get many different errors even tho i am defining them in hpp file

**Template.hpp**

```
#ifndef Template_hpp
#define Template_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T1 ,typename  T2>
class Temp
{
private:
    T1 item;
    T2 name;

public:
    Temp();
    Temp(T1 item, T2 name);
    T1 getItem();
    T2 getName();

};
#endif /* Template_hpp */
```

**Template.cpp**

```
#include "Template.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <typename T1 ,typename  T2>
Temp<T1,T2>:: Temp()
{

}
template <typename T1 ,typename  T2>

Temp<T1, T2>::  Temp( T1 item, T2 name)
{
    this->item=item;
    this->name=name;
}
template <typename T1 ,typename  T2>
T1 Temp<T1,T2>:: getItem()
{
    return this->item;
}

template <typename T1 ,typename  T2>
  T2 Temp<T1,T2>::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include "Template.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //Error here 
    Temp<int,string>t1(10,"zaid");
    t1.getName();
    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
Showing All Issues
Undefined symbol: Temp<int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::Temp(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)
```

Comment: short answer: templates should be defined in headers only

Comment: when i delete them from cpp class. it doesn't work too! @SebastianHoffmann

Comment: You can't just delete them entirely; you need to define them in the .hpp file.

Comment: @cigien, I am defining  them in  the .hpp file. i will post my .hpp class so you can see !

Comment: @cigien take a look at it right now, what's wrong with it? thank you!

Comment: It's the same issue that is covered in the dupe. Please read that. Even though you have defined the class in the .hpp, you need to define the member functions in the .hpp as well.